# Android auto layout method

Tags: android

I have a relative layout

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivLogo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/b2"
        android:text="Button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivLogo"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

which contains an imageview, textview, and two buttons, and what I want is to make a list of a info to be filled in this layout auto .. umm, like making in the java file "Heart.png", heart, www.heart.com, 69552874 .. then when I start the app the info I typed in the java class gets in the activity .. the "heart.png" gets in the ivLogo imageview, and the www.heart.com gets into b1 button, like this ..

I can achieve what i want using the xml but it will take a long of time and it'll be very slow because ill be many imageviews .. I want to make a list of things with their logo and name and num. and website , like can the java make a new relative layout for every info ..

like if i write

```
"Heart.png", heart1, www.heart.com, 69552874
"Heart.png", heart2, www.heart.com, 69552874
"Heart.png", heart3, www.heart.com, 69552874
```

I see in the app 3 relative layouts for each heart 1,2, and 3 ..
I want a method to do that not using the xml for each one make a new relative layout

isn't there something like makenewLayout etc ... ?

sorry for taking long, a two words hint will be nice to me <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this in code.

```
RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
iv.setId(ivid);
....
....
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setId(tvid);
tv.setText("My text");
...
layout.addView(iv);
layout.addView(tv);
setContentView(layout);
```

Put this in a function, and call the function for various images, textviews, etc.

Comment: ty, It worked fine, but I want many relative layouts under each other, if i do this it'll replace the layout and will only make one relative layout

Comment: For that first create your main relative layout programatically. Then, add the other relative layouts (inside the loop) to the main relative layout.